# Trying to create a form in javascript that will check my if else and redirect to a url if true

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a form that asks a simple question like "How many legs does a dog have?"(I know I haven't added that part yet) with three different outcomes.

1. nothing is in the input field "Oops! You haven't answered the clue!"
2. wrong answer in the input field "Sorry wrong answer"
3. correct answer in the input that will then show a URL to the next question. "Good Job! Go to the next question" www.url.com

This is what I have so far and I can't get it to see if my answer of "next page" to send me to a url

```
<pre>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x===null || x==="")
 {
  alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
  return false;
  } else (x==="next page")
   window.location="www.facebook.com"
}
</script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" method="post">
Answer: <input type="text" name="fname"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</html>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

`else` doesn't take conditions. You need to use `else if`, like so:

```
if (x===null || x==="")
{
  alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
  return false;
} else if (x==="next page") {
   window.location="www.facebook.com"
}
```

It's worth noting that you'll need to add `http://` in front of that URL. Also, since you're exiting the function via `return false` in the event of an unanswered clue, you can actually just use two `if` statements instead of the `else if`:

```
if (x===null || x==="")
{
  alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
  return false;
}

if (x==="next page")
{
   window.location="http://www.facebook.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are not calling your `validateForm` function on form submit. And you have some syntax issues in your code.

Your if statement should be...

```
if (x===null || x==="") {
    alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
    return false;
} else if (x==="next page") {
    window.location="www.facebook.com";
}
```

See below the edited version of your code with the different outcomes...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x===null || x==="") {
        alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
        return false;
    } else if (x != "4") {
        alert("Sorry wrong answer!");
        return false;
    } else if (x==="4") {
        alert("Good Job! Go to the next question");
        window.location="www.facebook.com"
    }

return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
Answer: <input type="text" name="fname"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get to the url, you need to add an `else if`:

```
<pre>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" method="post">
Answer: <input type="text" name="fname"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x === null || x ==="") {
        alert("Oops! You haven't answered the clue!");
    } else if (x === "next page") {
        alert("Good Job! Go to the next question");
        document.forms["myForm"].innerHTML += "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com\">Next Question</a>";
    } else {
        alert("Sorry wrong answer");
    }
    return false;
}
document.forms["myForm"].onsubmit = validateForm;
</script>
</html>
</pre>
```